# Is chrome.local.storage or chrome.runtime.sendMessage more secure for moving data between contexts?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm working on a Chrome extension that moves data between websites so it can be used for things like auto filling forms. It does this by handling all data processing in the context of the site the data originates from so that no cross-site requests or scripting happen (ie. taking a spreadsheet of data, crunching it down to just the parts I need, and storing that in an object or map for transport).

I have two options for how I can do this (that I'm aware of):

1. Use chrome.local.storage along with onEvent listeners to have one context write the data to local storage, then have the other see the change, take the data, and immediately set the storage variable back to null after processing.
2. Have the first context send a message with the data to the other via chrome.runtime.sendMessage where the message is then received and handled as needed.

I've used both methods of moving data in the past when working with script injectors, but I want be sure I'm using the most secure, even if the data being moved will usually be arbitrary.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: They are the same security-wise because a malicious page can theoretically break the isolation barrier of the content script via a Spectre-class exploit and then gain access to `chrome` API. Messaging is more effective because it doesn't write to disk. BTW there's also chrome.storage.session that doesn't write to disk.

Comment: @wOxxOm I've tried using session but it gives me an "Access to storage is not allowed from this context." error whenever I attempt to use session in a content script.

Comment: See chrome.storage.session.setAccessLevel()

Comment: @wOxxOm Ah, thanks! And I see this isn't the first time you've answered this question: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/il2DYn49HAw

Comment: @wOxxOm That worked, but in your opinion, would it be safer to not use storage at all and operate purely via message passing?